# Resample audio in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, pcm, avaudioengine, downsampling

I have a wave file recorded in 48000 sample rate. I need to play the recorded audio file in BLE device configured with 44100 sample rate. When the BLE device is disconnected from iPhone, i need to resume the playback in iPhone speaker which is configured by 48000 sample rate. So is it possible to resample the audio data to 44100 while sending data to connected BLE device
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is handled automatically for you if you use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here i need to use AuGraph, so when using AuGraph, the downsampling not working, so it creates some noise.

Comment: `AUGraph` has been deprecated by Apple, so you should be using `AVAudioEngine` instead.